# X509Certificate2UI equivalent on Mac Cocoa

Tags: macos, user-interface, certificate, monomac, xamarin.mac

I am creating an application on Mac using Monomac. I need to display a X509Certificate2 detail as part of one workflow. I did it in C# using X509Certificate2UI which comes in System.Security.Cryptography. Is there an equivalent system dialog on Mac which I can use to display the certificates similarly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for SFCertitificatePanel.

We do not have a binding for SFCertitificatePanel yet in Xamarin.Mac. I've filed a bug here.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28864

Depending on your required usage, it might be reasonable for you or to bang out the few selectors you need. Here's some documentation that may be useful.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/advanced_topics/binding-troubleshooting/